# Non-increasing arrangement

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, no-computers

We are arranging the numbers from 1 to 8 in an order so that three consecutive terms cannot be increasing. For example, 12345678 isn’t allowed but 81436572 is. How many ways are there to do it? Please don’t use computers.

Comment: Interesting question, I think  I have an idea for how to solve it, I'll give it a try in the morning.

Comment: The answer is obviously 049774, but I don't know in which sense is there a [tag:no-computer] answer. For such a low limit, it is certainly possible to follow the recurrence relation by hand, but it would be lengthy and boring. From [the linked paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02694), there doesn't seem to be a nice trick to solve it, although an interesting exponential generating function exists.

Comment: In case anyone reads WhatsUp's comment above and also the accepted answer and thinks "haha, what a doofus, said the answer was obvious and didn't even get it right", note that 049774 is an OEIS sequence number, not the actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the smartest approach but works:

(Confession: I did check with computer but only afterwards.)

> Use inclusion-exclusion to count all permutations with at least one increasing triplet.

> For each of the possible 6 positions there are 8x7x6x5x4 = 6720 such triplets.
>  
>  Pairwise intersections give increasing quadruplets,quintuplets or pairs of triplets. These contribute terms 5 x 1680, 4 x 336 and 6 x 56 x 20. The last term arises as 6 placements of two triplets, 8x7 ways to fill the two remaining cells and 20 ways to distribute 6 numbers over two tiplets.
>  
>  Threeway intersections give increasing quintuplets to septuplets, and triplets paired with quadruplets or quintuplets. Terms: 4 x 336, 3 x 2 x 56, 2 x 8, 2 x 3 x 8 x 35, 2 x 56
>  
>  Fourway intersections give increasing sextuplets to octuplets and pairs of quadruplets or triplets and quintuplets. Terms: 3 x 56, 2 x 3 x 8, 3 x 1, 70, 2 x 56
>  
>  Fiveway intersections give increasing septuplets and octuplets. Terms: 2 x 8, 4 x 1
>  
>  The full intersection gives the octuplet. Terms: 1

Taken together:

> 6 x 6720 - (5 x 1680 + 4 x 336 + 6 x 56 x 20) + (4 x 336 + 3 x 2 x 56 + 2 x 8 + 2 x 3 x 8 x 35 + 2 x 56) - (3 x 56 + 2 x 3 x 8 + 3 x 1 + 70 + 2 x 56) + (2 x 8 + 4 x 1) - 1 =
>  
>  6 x 6720 - 5 x 1680 - 117 x 56 + 208 x 8 - 70 =
>  
>  40320 - 8400 - 6552 + 1664 - 70 =
>  
>  26962
>  
>  This we have to subtract from the full permutation count 8! = 40320.

The final result is therefore:

> 13358

Comment: Was about to write up a similar answer, nicely summarized!